# Server Error - 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed

Tags: html, iis-7.5

I've just inherited a site and have moved a copy to a Windows Server 2008 test server. When I test the login process I'm getting a server error:

```
405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.
```

I've had a look at the login code and it is using a popover window to show the login form then when it is closed it appears to run jQuery script. This is all happening in the login.html page - here's how it currently looks:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      $("#myform").validate({
        //this is the submit = Log in
        submitHandler: function(form) {
          $.post('../login.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
            var theString = (data);
            var subString = theString.substr(0, 5);
            if (subString == "Error")
            //if the string starts with error then, guess what, it's an error!
            {
              $('#results').html(theString);
            } else //open the string as a link, it should be the database entry address returned
            {
              window.location = theString;
            }
          });
        } //close function(data)
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- START ADD THIS FOR LOG IN WINDOW -->
<!-- START Log in window -->

<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
<div id="popupContact">

  <h1> Log In.</h1>


  <table width="300" align="center">
    <form id="myform" method="POST">

      <tr>
        <td height="20">
          <div align="right"> User Name <input class="" name="username" type="text" size="30" /></div>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td height="20">
          <div align="right">Password <input name="password" type="password" size="30" /></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="5">
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="right" height="20">



          <input type="submit" name="action" value="LogIn" class="login_button" />

          <!--  class="login_button" style="font-size:11px"
    // class="my_password"  style="font-size:11px" -->
          <!--<a id="popupContactClose">x</a> -->
    </form>

    </td>
    </tr>

    <br />
  </table>

  <div class="error" id="results"> </div>
</div>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>

<!-- END Log in window -->
<!-- END ADD THIS FOR LOG IN WINDOW -->
```

From researching similar issues it appears to be a problem with submitting to a .html page that isn't accepting a POST request, but I can't find the settings to allow this (if this is indeed the actual issue). I can't find any settings so far in the current server that is hosting this successfully without this error message (also running Windows Server 2008).

I'm not looking to make any changes to the code at the moment (e.g. convert to PHP etc) just need to get it running on our test server by allowing a POST request to the login.html page.

Comment: In IIS, check the "Handler mappings" and look for the PHP handler. Double click it, select "Request restrictions" and then change the "Allowed verbs".

Comment: You also mention that the POST-request go to a .html page, but your code makes a post request to `../login.php`

Comment: @ulvesked I checked the PHP and it was set to "all verbs" already. Any other ideas here? The login.html page is doing the POST via the jQuery script to a PHP page, but it's all happening on the login.html page and if a successful result it redirects to another page.

Comment: Your jquery sends the login request to “../login.php” which means a php file in the parent folder. What is the contents of this file?